# change engine type from MyISAM to InnoDB

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, innodb, myisam

I want to change engine type from MyISAM to InnoDB.
What I Did:
Method 1:

1. Copy table structure in a new database.
2. Change table engine from MyISAM to InnoDB.
3. Export data from existing table (MyISAM).
4. Import data in a new table (InnoDB).
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]

Here, I can see the total rows of a table and the size of the table. But not see any record on browse.

Method 2:

1. Copy table structure in a new database.
2. Export data from the existing database.
3. Import data in a new database.
4. Change table engine from MyISAM to InnoDB. 
   [image]
   [image]

Here, I notice after change engine type many records are deleted.
In customer table imported records are 310749 after change engine type, I see only 243898, loss total 66851 records.

What is wrong with this?
Any other way to change the type from MyISAM to InnoDB without loss data.

Answer (score 2):

Simply do `ALTER TABLE foo ENGINE=InnoDB;`  But that does it 'in-place'.  If you want the new table in a different database:

```
CREATE TABLE db2.foo LIKE db1.foo;
ALTER TABLE  db2.foo ENGINE=InnoDB;  -- and possibly other changes, see blog below
INSERT INTO  db2.foo
    SELECT * FROM db1.foo;       -- copy data over

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db1.foo;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db2.foo;    -- compare exact number of rows
```

The number of rows -- If you are using `SHOW TABLE STATUS` to see that, be aware that MyISAM provides an exact number of rows, but InnoDB only approximates the number.  Use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo` to get the exact number of rows.

Here, let me knock the cobwebs off my old blog on moving from MyISAM to InnoDB:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb

Comment: Thanks for your time. I will try this way and update